# What to do with forgotten, uncovered raw chicken in the freezer?

Tags: chicken, freezing, raw-meat

Three weeks ago I bought chicken breasts on sale and froze them uncovered on a pan lined with wax paper.

I meant to come back the next day to vacuum seal them but of course I forgot about them or I wouldn't be posting about it.

Additionally, I don't see any ice build up or noticeable freezer burn.

Here's a picture for reference:
[image]

Should I pick up where I left off and continue with the vacuum seal or would that be pointless because of some potential loss of quality or safety issue?

My original intention was to use them for just about anything, but now I'm cautious and am leaning towards boiling them and using them in a pulled chicken recipe to cover any flavor/texture issues.

I'm relatively new to freezing raw meet so any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Polygorial that sounds like a good new question.  Want to ask it ?  I'd make some guesses.

Comment: @Criggie surely a question that's specifically about why kraftydevil didn't use a cover would not be on-topic as an independent question.

Comment: @Polygorial - I meant to freeze it for a minimal time for which I figured freezer burn would be negligible. I intended to come back in an hour and then vacuum seal it - but alas I got distracted and forgot to finish the job.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There’s no safety issue; frozen is frozen. It’s  hard to tell from the colors in the photo but they do look a bit dehydrated. Assuming your freezer doesn’t smell weird, this would cause no taste issues and only minor texture issues. They should be fine for pretty much any preparation method other than steaming (even that would be fine if shredded).

Comment: agree...I would thaw in fridge and use, or vac and return to freezer (just wanted to add the -OK to package and return to freezer part).